# What is the jQuery equivalent of Scriptaculous?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Is it jQuery animate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mixture of the core [jQuery Effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I think this does actually answer the question as asked.